# Get users from an AD Security group inside a SharePoint group

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory

How do we get the users from an Active directory group inside a SharePoint group. In my project i need to send emails to all the members in a a SharePoint group, and the SharePoint group contains Users as well as a security group in Active directory. So how do i loop through all these??

i tried SPFieldUserValueCollection to get all the groups and users and checking whether each item is a group or user but its not working??
Can any one help me with this???

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getprincipalsingroup.aspx) method to do that. 
`input` parameter is a NT account name of the security group.

Comment: It is name of security group in your domain. For example domain\group.

Answer (score 2):

To check whether the user is an SPUser or domain group you can use below property:

```
SPUser.IsDomainGroup
```

This link details about how to fetch the user details by looping through the AD Group.
http://christopherclementen.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/get-all-users-from-sharepoint-group-including-active-directory-group-v2/

Comment: I tried this...but its not working for default AD domain users group...Otherwise its working fine..